# How to apply pivottable.js on dynamic html table data coming from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, json, pivottable.js

I am retrieving everyday sales data from MYSQL database using PHP and displaying it in HTML table in multidimensional way. Want to get subtotals by category of day by day sales to in it column.

Then I came to know about `pivottable.js` and `subtotal.js` plugin but the problem is this works with `json` or `CSV` data. How can I do this with printed HTML table?

Any idea or solution?

Comment: So I understand the question: you want to use PivotTable.js to add a column to an existing table?